# my asp.net mvc 2.0 application fails with error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm new in asp.net mvc 2.
I'm trying to list all data from one table(ms sql server table). as ORM I use Entity Framework. now, I'm tried to write something to do this:

**Model:**

```
    private uqsEntities _uqsEntity;
    public permissionRepository(uqsEntities uqsEntity)
    {
        _uqsEntity = uqsEntity;
    }

    public string getUserID()
    {
        return _uqsEntity.userPermissions.FirstOrDefault().ID.ToString();
    }
```

**controller:**

```
    private DataManager _dataManager;
    public HomeController(DataManager datamanager)
    {
        _dataManager = datamanager;

    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = _dataManager.Permission.getUserID();

        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
```

when I run app. , my app. fails.

> No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for
>   this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No
>   parameterless constructor defined for
>   this object.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean&
>   bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   fillCache) +230
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +80
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error
>   occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'uqs.Controllers.HomeController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +190    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   +68    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller,
>   IControllerFactory& factory) +118
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +46
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object
>   extraData) +13
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8679186    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

please, somebody, help me to catch problem.

**Other classes:**
***DataManager.cs***

```
public class DataManager
 {
    private uqsEntities _entity;

    public DataManager(string connectionString)
    {
        this._entity = new uqsEntities(connectionString);
    }

    private permissionRepository _permissionsRepository;
    public permissionRepository Permission
    {
        get
        {
            if (_permissionsRepository == null)
                _permissionsRepository = new permissionRepository(_entity);
            return _permissionsRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

***ControllerFactory.cs***

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public Type controllerType { get; set; }
        public ControllerFactory()
        {

        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
                base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["uqsEntities"].ConnectionString;
            return Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, new DataManager(connectionString)) as IController;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it, like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            //by this code:
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ControllerFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the parameter-less constructor for your controller?  ManagePermissionsController

The default controller factory requires one, so unless you create your own Controller factory you'll need to add one and change the way you initialize your DataManager.

Comment: thanks, please, can you say, what is wrong in my ControllerFactory class?

Comment: Where is your controller factory?  The stack trace says "DefaultControllerFactory" which implies it's not using your controller factory.